# secondary Y axis with short bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am fine with simple bar graph but when I need add secondary Y axis. I have some difficulties, hope someone can help me so my python can look like Excel version.

My expected outcome is below.

x axis : Stock

y1 axis :Q1 , Q2 & Q3 results in percentage in bar chart

y2 axis : Net Exposure in percentage in dots or a line without linked each one

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Stock': ['A', 'B', 'C'],

'Q1 Result': [-0.005, 0.02, 0.0434],

'Q2 Result': [0.0248, 0.003, 0.0051],

'Q3 Result': [0.0723, 0.0071, -0.0035],

'Net Exposure': [0.8511, 0.5873,-0.4671]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
ax=df.plot.bar(x = 'Stock', y = ['Q1 Result', 'Q2 Result','Q3 Result'])

ax2=df.plot.line(x = 'Stock', y = ['Net Exposure'])

df.plot.line(ax=ax.twinx(), secondary_y=range(-100, 100))
```

I get below graph from the code

[image]

And here is what excel give me
[image: By Excel]

Comment: Hi @Jodie - the link for Data shows the python graph. Please provide data in text format. What are you expecting to achieve? You need bar graph (no lines) and2 y-axes? What should be on the second Y-axis. It is not very clear in the question.

Comment: yes just see it, now looking for editing

Comment: Changing `df.plot.line(ax=ax.twinx(), secondary_y=range(-100, 100))` to `df.plot.scatter(x='Stock', y='Net Exposure', ax=ax.twinx())` may give you what you expected.

Comment: Thanks Z-Y.L. It works but is there any possible turn those three dots into a short horizontal line and can I control the length?

Comment: @Jodie - Updated code to set legend as the line was missing. Check updated code. Let me know if anything is missing

Comment: @Jodie You can set the marker using `marker='_'`, and control the size by `s` parameter. e.g. `df.plot.scatter(x='Stock', y='Net Exposure', ax=ax.twinx(), marker='_', s=200)`. Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. Code is pretty self explanatory, you had most of the pieces there, just had to make a few adjustments...

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick #For formatting the y-labels

data = {'Stock': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
'Q1 Result': [-0.005, 0.02, 0.0434],
'Q2 Result': [0.0248, 0.003, 0.0051],
'Q3 Result': [0.0723, 0.0071, -0.0035],
'Net Exposure': [0.8511, 0.5873,-0.4671]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5)) #You can adjust figure size here
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df[['Q1 Result', 'Q2 Result','Q3 Result']].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1, legend=False) #Diff is ax=ax1 in side plot 
df['Net Exposure'].plot(kind='line', marker='d', c = 'r', ax=ax2)
ax1.set_ylabel("Quarterly Results")
ax2.set_ylabel('Net Exposure')
ax1.set_xticklabels(df.Stock.unique(), rotation=0, fontsize=12) #X-labels added
fig.legend(loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 0.88)) #Add and adjust legend
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter()) #Convert numbers to %.Will need to be divided by 100 
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
```

**Output plot**

[image]